# Difference in post output

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two scripts, one is a Prestashop DHL label creator, and the other one is our company's internal sales application. I'm trying to combine the two together so we can generate DHL label from the application without visiting the shop's admin panel. And now to the  core of the problem.
The Prestashop DHL module sends a POST with parameters looking like this:

> Receiver:Address:HouseNumber: #value

and our internal sales app sends POST with parameters looking like this:

> Receiver[Address][HouseNumber]: #value

This may be a stupid question, but what's the difference?

Here's the code that generates the POST in our app

```
function generateDHLLabel()
{
    jQuery.post("prestashop_link", { 
        DhlShipmentId:'',   
        DhlOrderId  :'',
        DhlShipmentCreationDateTime:'',
        ShipmentPreset:{ldelim}ShipmentPresetId :   1{rdelim},
        ServiceType:    'AH',
        DropOffType:    'REGULAR_PICKUP',
        LabelType:  'BLP',
        Content:    'content',
        Comment :'',
        Reference:  5508,
        ShippingPaymentType:    'SHIPPER',
        PaymentType:    'BANK_TRANSFER',
        BillingAccountNumber    :'',
        CostsCenter :'',
        ShipmentDate:   '2019-05-09',
        ShipmentStartHour:  '09:00',
        ShipmentEndHour:    '19:00',
        ParcelIdent :'',
        Postnummer  :'',
        ParcelPostalCode :'',   
        Receiver:{ldelim}
            Address:{ldelim}Name:   'Name+Surname',
                            Street: 'Street+1',
                            HouseNumber:'',
                            ApartmentNumber:'', 
                            OriginalAddressString:  'Name+Surname,+Street+1,+00-000+City,+Country',
                            ParseAlert:'',
                            PostalCode: '00000',
                            City:   'CITY',
                            Country:    'PL'{rdelim},
            Contact:{ldelim}Name:   'Name+Surname',
                            Phone:  '000000000',
                            Email:  'mail@domain.com'{rdelim}{rdelim},
        Package:{ldelim}Type:   'PACKAGE',
                        Weight: '4',
                        Width:  '30',
                        Height: '30',
                        Length: '20',
                        Quantity:   '1'{rdelim},
        SpecialServices:{ldelim}S_UBEZP:    '1',
                                UBEZP_Value:    '123.49',
                                UBEZP_CurrencyUnitAlert :'',
                                S_COD:  '1',
                                COD_Value:  '123.49',
                                COD_CurrencyUnitAlert:'',
                                ROD_Instruction :'',
                                OriginalCurrencyUnit:   'PLN'{rdelim},
        Neighbour:{ldelim}Name:'',
                            Street:'',
                            HouseNumber:'',
                            ApartmentNumber:'',
                            PostalCode:'',
                            City:'',
                            Phone:'',
                            Email:''{rdelim},






        Action:'Send'


    }, function(data) {
        window.location.href = '{site_url()}app/packing/order-packing/{$this->uri->segment(4)}';
    });

}
```

Comment: That JS it littered with syntax errors.

Comment: I think your only option here is to specify your parameter names in the jQuery post data explicitly the way you need them. That also means you can not use nested objects, but need to list them all individually: `'Receiver:Address:Name' : 'Name+Surname', 'Receiver:Address:Street:' : 'Street+1'`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out already :) I thought that the data posted by prestashop was an array, but it isn't, those are just variables named something:someting etc.

Answer (score 1):

One has square brackets in the name. The other has colons in the name. That's all.

The software reading the request will probably care which you use.

Comment: Yeah, but here's the thing, I'm not using either. The code for this part looks like this on my side:
Receiver:{Address:{HouseNumber:'',}}

Comment: @tuned — Are you asking why some code (which we can't see) given some input (which we also can't see) is outputting something with colons or square brackets? How should we know?

Comment: @tuned — The *difference* is still the same. Maybe you aren't asking the question you are trying to ask.

Comment: Maybe. correct me if I'm wrong but the are these arrays right?

Comment: @tuned — Some software which parses them might treat them as arrays (or key:value pair maps or something else). In the URL encoded data format they are just key names with `[`, `]` and `:` having no special meaning.